# Cannot install Kubuntu 19.10 with encryption using manual partitioner

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu, encryption

I tried to install **Kubuntu 19.10** inside VirtualBox with **full disk encryption** using the **manual partitioner**, but I am unable to do so. I just cannot setup the luks partition at all.

I have to avoid  using the guided method as it will erase everything else on the disk (or so it says, haven’t tried it).

I am trying to do this to learn, because I will replicate the process on a real disk later.

The problem is produced by the following steps:

1. Start the installer
2. Select manual partitioning option instead of guided
3. Create 100MB partition for EFI System Partition
4. Create 1GB partition for /boot
5. Use the rest of the space to create (or try to create) a partition to be used as physical volume for luks encryption

And here comes the problem. On Ubuntu, Xubuntu, etc., the partitioner would ask for a password for the encryption, and would quickly map the encrypted volume on `/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt`, but Kubuntu does not ask for a password. Instead, it just shows the type of the partition to be `"crypto"`, (sda1 here is shown as efi, and sda2 is shown as ext4), and does not map it to `/dev/mapper/*`. So now I have no partition to mount on `/`.

I can't proceed to the next screen without selecting a partition for `/`.

I tried to do another thing.

1. I first used the `gdisk` to create the partitions.
2. Formatted the partitions:

```
mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda3
```

3. Mapped the encrypted partition:

```
cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt
```

Then I proceeded to the installer.

This time there is a new partition on the list: `/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt`, because I already unlocked and mapped it. Now I can select sda1 as efi, sda2 as /boot, and sda3 as *Physical device for encryption* (it still doesn't ask for a password). **But as soon as I click on `/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt`, the installer crashes.**

If it's a bug then it may be a rare one, cause I can't find any info on the internet about it.

**So how can I install Kubuntu 19.10 on an encrypted partition using the manual partitioning (without erasing other/previous partitions)?**

UPDATE: I have experimented with various OSes, these are the results:

**WORKS AS EXPECTED WITH MY CUSTOM SETUP:**

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Ubuntu 19.10
Linux Mint 19.3
Xubuntu 18.04
Lubuntu 18.04
Lubuntu 19.10 (with slightly different steps[1])
OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and Leap [2]
```

**DOES NOT WORK, PRODUCES AFOREMENTIONED PROBLEMS:**

```
Kubuntu 18.04
Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Neon
```

[1] I just have to create the partition, and select the *Encrypt* check mark, then I am able to provide a new password.
[2] I could be using openSUSE, but Tumbleweed is not very stable, and Leap is not the latest.

Comment: Kubuntu and KDE Neon use different installers and thus the answers will not be same.

Comment: And yet the result is the same. I guess this is some internal problem of KDE apps?

Comment: Please if you know how to achieve the goal, please  do tell me. I'm willing to settle on any of the two.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Your question as written I see as off-topic, and you've made assumptions that don't make sense. Kubuntu installs with the exact same procedure as Xubuntu (Kubuntu just uses a skin that looks like `calamares` over its `ubiquity` but outside of looks, it's almost indentical).  Neon uses `calamares` like Lubuntu does for some releases, but you've skipped necessary release details anyway so specifics cannot be provided.

Comment: I just did it again, and it happened as described. So this problem is persistent. Also, I removed mentions of KDE Neon to be more on topic. Please suggest how I may improve the question.

Comment: You mention it working on Xubuntu (and Ubuntu), release info there would be useful, as I'm not aware of differences (beyond visual (skin) difference I've already mentioned), and the release comparison would be my starting point for a comparison.  Your emphasis I read as being Qt/KDE based (thus seeing link with neon), where modern Lubuntu would have issues too, but without xubuntu/ubuntu releases my focus is on installer (which is `ubiquity` in all of kubuntu, xubuntu & ubuntu desktop)

Comment: **Manual Full Disk Encryption** This method worked for me: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption

Comment: @guiverc I have updated the question with my test results. If you have the time, please try them. Or you can forward them to the developers, they may be able or willing to look into this.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Please file the bug report yourself, (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (though I've seen chatter on kubuntu *only* install issues for 20.04 since your post but it could be different issues; bug reports are the best place for discussion - this is a user support site & not for bug reports).  https://kubuntu.org/news/testing-for-the-beta-help-needed/